# Async CTP Task.WhenAll issue

Tags: c#

I am stuck on something which appears simple but I cannot see what i'm doing wrong.  I have a simple class structure 'StaticQuote' which describes values returned from a complex calculation for which I am trying to find the lowest value.  Because the Calculate call is expensive I am creating an array of tasks so the calculations execute in parallel, and am then using a Task.WhenAll to wait until they have all finished before comparing the results (which are stored in StaticQuote objects).  The problem is that when trying to return the array of StaticQuotes I am getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Services.QuoteGeneratorAsync.StaticQuote[]>'` to `'Services.QuoteGeneratorAsync.StaticQuote[]'`

I have seen similar examples with strings etc where this assignment works perfectly so cannot understand which the right hand side is not returning an array of StaticQuote results?  I am new to multi threaded code and the Async CTP.  Can anyone provide the answer?  Many thanks.

example problem:

```
List<Task<StaticQuote>> Calculations = new List<Task<StaticQuote>>();
foreach()
{
Calculations.Add(TaskEx.RunEx(() => Calculate(...my params....)));                                             
}
StaticQuote[] Quotes=TaskEx.WhenAll<StaticQuote>(Calculations);  --//this line won't compile
```

Answer (score 1):

`TaskEx.WhenAll` returns a `Task<T[]>` which indicates when all the other tasks have finished. So you want:

```
StaticQuote[] quotes = await TaskEx.WhenAll(Calculations);
```

The `await` expression "unwraps" a `Task<T>` to a `T`. So elsewhere if you've got:

```
Task<string> downloadTask = webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
string result = await downloadTask;
```

it's exactly the same thing - it's just that the `WhenAll` version is slightly more complicated because it's got a *collection* of task inputs and outputs, instead of a single one.

Obviously in order to use `await` you have to be in an `async` method to start with.

If all of this is still confusing, you might want to read my [blog posts about async](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/async/default.aspx), as well as [those of Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/async/). (There are plenty of others available too, of course.)

Comment: Many thanks Jon - won't await cause the thread to move on though? I have a top level for loop which calls the whole thing again so was trying to conrol the number of threads on the go at once.  I saw this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174806/what-is-taskex-whenall-in-the-async-ctp why doesn't the assignment he's doing in here work for me?  How's Tony the Pony? :)

Comment: @dustybin: `await` will cause the method to return to the caller, but then it'll come back into this method when all the tasks have completed. The assignment within the linked question *does* use `await`, so I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: Yes the example uses await but I was concerned that if the thread carries on it will spawn the next lot of calculate threads from my outer loop.  It shouldn't be a problem, I was just trying to see if I could control the number of threads as Calculate() takes 3-5 seconds to return.  Didn't want too many of them running at once.  I was at your DDD Modern .Net day presentation on Async last year (awesome) but this is the first chance i've had to use it.  Also just realised WhenAll has a ".Result" property - doh.  will read the blogs...cheers.

Comment: @dustybin: The async method won't continue until all the tasks have completed - that's what `await` is all about. The *calling* method will be able to continue, but that's a different matter :)

Comment: The outer loop is in my calling method :)

Comment: @dustybin: If you want that to wait until everything's completed, then perhaps you don't want an async method to start with? Perhaps just `Parallel.ForEach` from .NET 4?

Comment: I think you're right. I'm enjoying discovering these issues tho! I think I now have bigger problems, just got the message "OracleConnection does not support parallel transactions", that should keep my busy for a while :)  Thanks for all the help.